# Search for escaping character \ in sublime text 2

Tags: unicode, sublimetext2

Could anyone help me understand why I am unable to search for \ or unicode in Sublime Text 2?

Searching for \u001B is not found although clearly in the file and an error occurs when searching for just ...

[image: See attached image]

Obviously doing something wrong but no idea what.

Answer (score 4):

You have 'Regular expression' matching enabled (this is the leftmost button next to the search field). Since backslashes are used in 'regex' expressions, to search for a backslash, you would need to search for `\\`

To do simple, text-based matching (i.e., not use regular expressions), simply click the first button to disable Regular expression matching. You should then be able to search for `\`

Comment: Thanks Greg. Top advice.

Comment: Thank you for providing the screenshot, it made for an easy troubleshooting! :-)